# AWS IoT MQTT over WebSocket Protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I've been following the AWS IoT docs trying to get started with the MQTT tutorial at 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html#mqtt-ws
to set up a WebSocket connection to AWS IoT in a web application. The first step is to initiate a WebSocket connection by making a GET request to an endpoint created by following the steps in the tutorial but I'm getting this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load <my endpoint> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

I was wondering if anyone has encountered this error and if so, how they resolved it?

Here's a link to the code https://github.com/dwyl/learn-aws-iot/blob/2c8035728ec8228e296580c8714f3f7ace870fbe/src/js/components/App.js

Comment: Is the failing GET request to the describe-endpoint API or to open the WebSocket? If trying to open the WebSocket, are you using a Javascript client which supports WebSockets or making a normal HTTP request to the endpoint?

Comment: I'm making a normal HTTP request through XMLHttpRequest to open the websocket using a url of the form ```wss://<endpoint>.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com/mqtt``` which has been signed using the amazon signature version 4

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of how I'm opening the channel. I'm using Cognito unauth roles as a subscriber. I'm using the JS Paho client as well.

http://draw.kyleroche.com/main.js

Comment: Thanks! Can you share your `SigV4Utils.getSignedUrl` function?

Comment: Yeah it would be great if you could share this utils function. Can't seem to find it anywhere in the docs

Comment: See [here](http://draw.kyleroche.com/sigv4utils.js) for the utility function being used.

Comment: More info in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html).

Answer (score 4):

AWS Labs has also posted an MQTT over WebSockets reference example here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-iot-examples